# Getting the current user in a minimal api

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, minimal-apis

I am trying to refactor my api into a minimal api. Previously I've been using ControllerBase.HttpContext to get the user like this:

```
var emial = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

The method that I want to use for my endpoint mapping should be something like this:

```
public static void MapSurveyEndpoints(this WebApplication app) {
    app.MapPost("/api/Surveys", AddSurveysAsync);
}

public static async Task<Survey> AddSurveysAsync(ISurveyRepository repo, Survey survey) {
    var email = ...; //get current user email
    survey.UserEmail = email;
    return await repo.AddSurveysAsync(survey);
}
```

What would be another approach for getting the user without using controller?

Comment: What about how you want to do it isn't working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Minimal APIs have several parameter binding sources for handlers, including [special types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#special-types), like `HttpContext` as suggested in another answer, but if you need only the user info you can add just `ClaimsPrincipal` (which is one of the special types) parameter to your handler:

```cs
app.MapGet("/...", (..., ClaimsPrincipal user) => user.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: Nice observation, so in my case I would get the email as such: user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)

Answer (score 4):

You can take the `HttpContext` as a parameter of your endpoint. ASP.NET Core will then provide that to you.

```
public static async Task<Survey> AddSurveysAsync(
    HttpContext context,
    ISurveyRepository repo,
    Survey survey)
```